# save array of object contain image in my iOS app

Tags: ios

I want to save array of users , every user has name ,phone ,image and video , what is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a photo URL and a video URL instead of media. Those URLs can be references from your server or database. A Sample code could be:

```
class User {

    var name: String?
    var phone: Int?
    var photoUrl: String?
    var videoUrl: String?

    init(name: String, phone: Int, photoUrl: String, videoUrl: String) {

        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.photoUrl = photoUrl
        self.videoUrl = videoUrl
    }
}

var users = [User]()

let user1 = User(name: "Something", phone: 123456, photoUrl: "SomeUrl", videoUrl: "SomeUrl")
let user2 = User(name: "Something", phone: 123456987, photoUrl: "SomeUrl", videoUrl: "SomeUrl")

users.append(user1)
users.append(user2)
```

Comment: and then save this in userdefault ?

Comment: No, don’t save in user defaults. If you only need local storage then look at Core Data. It has an option to automatically store binary data as external files but hides that detail from you.

Answer (score 1):

try to use core data in your App or realm pod :D